# Measuring Stride distance wirelessly

Tags: sensor, wireless, rfid, distance

I'm trying to fit two sensors in a shoe each (such that each shoe has one sensor). their purpose being to calculate the stride length of a person, as a person takes a stride, the distance between two sensors will "peak", thus indicating a stride. However, I don't know what is out there or what sensors to use. I was thinking of using RFID 433 MHz sensor, or ASHR, but not sure how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way is to find a room tiled with 12" square floor tiles. Walk 10 paces across that room and count how many tiles you passed. Divide by 10 and you have the length of your stride in feet, with no wires involved.

Comment: Thanks... I was thinking more of live biofeedback when on a running track etc.

Comment: I think you will have a hard time doing this.

Comment: But one could use some sort of radio/induction coil scheme between the two shoes.  Not sending and receiving pulses like RADAR, but measuring how strong of a signal a coil in one shoe induces in the other, or something along those lines.

Comment: You might be good with a simple 3 axis accelerometer. Orient it such that one axis corresponds to forward motion and another corresponds to downward motion, so you can detect when a person begins the striding by detecting forward motion and start integrating that, and stop when you detect a sharp deceleration corresponding to a step.

Answer (score 1):

Use one shoe (master) to emit a sonic pulse. Use the other shoe (slave) to receive it and immediately transmit it back to the first shoe. The time taken (as calculated by the first shoe) to send and then receive a pulse is related to the stride length.

Radio won't work because the biggest delay is the turnaround time from reception to retransmission and, given the slight variations in turnaround time (due to CPU not being 100% on the ball) will be longer than the transmission time by a thousand times!

Comment: Thank you, any suggestions on what kind of transmitters/receivers or technology I should use? I am pretty new to all of this.

Comment: If you are still working on this, here's an AN from TI about ultrasonic distance measurement using a MSP430. http://www.ti.com/mcu/docs/litabsmultiplefilelist.tsp?sectionId=96&tabId=1502&literatureNumber=slaa136a&docCategoryId=1&familyId=914

Also here's an ultrasonic transceiver. You'll need 2 of them and you'll need to power them somehow while they are attached to the person's shoes but they are quite nice.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/639